# Integrating mautic server with another java application

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, openid, saml, mautic

I'm new to mautic. We have an java application that manages authentication of its users. It also support openid connect/ jwt/oauth flows. We are planning to use mautic as a separate server . How do I integrate my application with mautic? Seems like the mautic only support SAML for SSO. Does that mean our application now need to act as SAML IDP? Or is there a way to get mautic to support JWT/oauth/openid connect

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify why you need to authenticate users, will these all be people who will be working in the back-end of Mautic?  Otherwise you won't need to use authentication for regular folk accessing resources or landing pages you create, they don't need to log in.

The developer documentation would be a good place to start for all things technical/development, which you can find here: https://developer.mautic.org/ - this includes information about authorisation and specifically OAuth which might be helpful: https://developer.mautic.org/#authorization.

You'll find some documentation on using the SAML function here if you're going that route: https://www.mautic.org/docs/en/authentication/saml.html

Happy to help if you get stuck!